# Browser Plugin w/ jQuery - Capture DOM Updates (Facebook specifically)

Tags: jquery, facebook, dom

I am currently writing a browser plugin that inserts some HTML elements onto the page.  I am wondering how I can make my plugin detect when the website has updated the DOM and then go and modify the HTML as needed.

In this specific example I am trying to insert some HTML on Facebook. Using the $(document).ready() function is not working since Facebook is updating their page with AJAX.  This seems to be true when a user navigates to a group page as well as when the user scrolls down the page and it loads more info.

I can't simply attach a click or scroll listener using .live() since I still would need to wait for the page to finish updating before I can change the DOM.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can load the comment using JavaScript with the following code:

```
var abc = $("#fb-comments-wrapper");
var b = "<fb:comments href=\"page_url"\ num_posts=\"2\" width=\"420\"></fb:comments>"
abc.html(b);
```

After this call the following code  which will load the facebook comment into the `div` named 'fb-comments-wrapper' and call the upon the  'facebookCommentLoaded' function when loaded:

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('container_of_fb-comments-wrapper'),facebookCommentLoaded);
```

Your 'facebookCommentloadedfunction' can do the things you want:

```
function facebookCommentLoaded() {
    $(".uiBoxYellow").css("display","none");
    $(".commentas").css("display","none");
}
```

I was however unable to make any style changes to the facebook div's. Somehow they were not available through `document.getElementByClass`. Seems facebook modifies the dom in a way that prevents custom CSS.